# Libavcodec (FFMPEG) D3D11 hardware acceleration not outputting hardware frames

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, h.264, direct3d, libavcodec

#### The Problem

I'm trying to get FFMPEG to output D3D11 2D textures directly as Frames. As I understand, this is infact possible. The reasoning for this, is I can then decode the YUV format directly on the GPU and then display it without having to Marshall it back to the CPU.

**My problem is that I can't get the decoder to actually output frames in the desired format, they are always software `YUV420J`.**

Is this because I'm not initializing the decoder properly? Or perhaps there is some other configuration I'm missing.

---

#### The Details

I've been following the [example](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/hw_decode.c) for the most part, with a few minor differences:

1. I only have to deal with 1 format, raw h264, so I'm manually configuring the Decoder to use `AV_CODEC_ID_H264`
2. I've all ready initialized the D3DDevice and Context and so am using `av_hwdevice_ctx_init` over `av_hwdevice_ctx_create`. (I have tried just using `av_hwdevice_ctx_create` and got the same results)
3. As mentioned earlier, I don't want to use `av_hwframe_transfer_data` because I want to keep the data on the GPU as a texture and immediately display it.

Here is my initialization code:

```
    AVHWDeviceType type = AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_D3D11VA;

    hw_pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_D3D11;

    _codec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264); // NOT SURE IF THIS IS THE HW SUPPORTED FMT
    
    int i;
    for (i = 0;; i++) {
        const AVCodecHWConfig* config = avcodec_get_hw_config(_codec, i);
        if (!config) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Decoder %s does not support device type %s.\n",
                _codec->name, av_hwdevice_get_type_name(type));
            return;
        }
        if (config->methods & AV_CODEC_HW_CONFIG_METHOD_HW_DEVICE_CTX &&
            config->device_type == type) {
            hw_pix_fmt = config->pix_fmt;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!(_codecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(_codec))) {
        // ERROR!
        return;
    }

    _hw_device_ctx = av_hwdevice_ctx_alloc(type);

    _device_ctx = reinterpret_cast<AVHWDeviceContext*>(_hw_device_ctx->data);
    _d3d11va_device_ctx = reinterpret_cast<AVD3D11VADeviceContext*>(_device_ctx->hwctx);
    _d3d11va_device_ctx->device = dev;

    _codecCtx->hw_device_ctx = av_buffer_ref(_hw_device_ctx);


    if (av_hwdevice_ctx_init(_codecCtx->hw_device_ctx) < 0) {
        return;
    }


    if (avcodec_open2(_codecCtx, _codec, NULL) < 0) {
        return;
    }

    _parser = av_parser_init(_codec->id);
    _packet = av_packet_alloc();
```

I'm doing the standard things to decode, and know it works because I've used software decoding just fine, but here it is anyway:

```
void Decoder::Load(std::vector<std::byte> data) {
    int data_size = data.size();

    int bytesRead = 0;
    int bytesParsed = 0;

    while (data_size > 0) {
        bytesParsed = av_parser_parse2(
            _parser,
            _codecCtx,
            &_packet->data,
            &_packet->size,
            (uint8_t*)&data[bytesRead],
            data.size() - bytesRead,
            AV_NOPTS_VALUE,
            AV_NOPTS_VALUE,
            0);

        bytesRead += bytesParsed;
        data_size -= bytesParsed;

        if (bytesParsed < 0) {
            //std::cout << "Error while parsing packet" << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        if (_packet->size) {
            int ret = avcodec_send_packet(_codecCtx, _packet);
            if (ret < 0) {
                //std::cout << "Error Sending Packet for Decoding" << std::endl;
                return;
            }

            while (ret >= 0) {
                AVFrame* frame = av_frame_alloc();
                ret = avcodec_receive_frame(_codecCtx, frame);

                if (frame->format != AV_PIX_FMT_D3D11) { // <--- THIS NEVER EVALUATES AS FALSE, IT'S ALWAYS THE YUV420J FORMAT, NOT THE HARDWARE FORMAT
                    break;
                }

                if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
                    break;
                }
                else if (ret < 0) {
                    //std::cout << "Error During Decoding" << std::endl;
                    return;
                }

                _frameQueue.push(frame);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### How I built FFMPEG:

```
./../../sources/ffmpeg/configure \
             --prefix=./../../installed \
             --toolchain=msvc \
             --arch=x86_64 \
             --enable-yasm  \
             --enable-asm \
             --enable-shared \
             --enable-dxva2 \
             --enable-d3d11va \
             --disable-static \
             --enable-gpl \
             --extra-ldflags="-LIBPATH:./../../installed/lib/" \
             --extra-cflags="-I./../../installed/include/"
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but using ffmpeg on Windows is usually suboptimal. The OS already includes better equivalent, the framework is called Media Foundation. If you want to decode video on GPU into D3D11 textures, use higher-level `IMFMediaEngine` interface. Example: https://github.com/Const-me/vis_avs_dx/blob/master/avs_dx/DxVisuals/Effects/Video/MF/Player.h

Comment: TY for the reply. I did come across this in my initial research, however the statement:
> Enables an application to play audio or video files.
Made me dismiss it. In my case, I'm actually getting a raw h264 stream from a device driver, not a file. Further, it's not in a container like mp4, which typically means I need access to something lower level. Do you think IMFMedia engine would still work? I need to feed in a raw bitstream rather than a filename.

Comment: Possible, but relatively hard. A short version - create custom `IMFMediaSource` for your device, create `IMFMediaEngineExtension` to supply that source to media engine, and supply the extension object in `MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_EXTENSION` attribute when creating the media engine. You can cheat instead: write code which serves encoded video from your device in RTSP format, and use IMFMediaSource to play an URL like `rtsp://user:password@127.0.0.1:31337/live`

Comment: Also, if your device is a camera or similar, it might come with Windows drivers which expose the device to Media Foundation. If that's the case, the media source is already there, and it should be easy to decode the video with media foundation, using a source reader.

Comment: Ahh yeah, all ready went down the media source route. It was very ideal, and was overly complicated. Like I don't need to seek, etc. I just need to render video and nothing more

Comment: If your source doesn’t support seek, don’t return `MFMEDIASOURCE_CAN_SEEK` flag from `IMFMediaSource.GetCharacteristics` method of your media source, and you won’t need to support anything related to seek.